# C# struct.Clear() not working

Tags: c#

Note: The example uses simplified versions of the class and struct. The actual class and struct are from the Unity event system, [here (class)](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/5fc21bb4ecf4b40ff6630057edaa070252909b2e/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/EventData/PointerEventData.cs?at=4.6) and [here (struct)](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/5fc21bb4ecf4b40ff6630057edaa070252909b2e/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/RaycastResult.cs?at=4.6)

I have a struct, with a clear function that clears all info in it:

```
public struct MyResult
{
    public float index;
    public int depth;

    public void Clear()
    {
        index = 0;
        depth = 0;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class that use this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public MyResult result { get; set; }
     // Wasn't a property but a field in the original question
     // I simplified the classes too much, sorry.
}
```

Now I have an instance of `MyClass` and I call `theInstance.result.Clear();` but this doesn't set `index`and `depth` back to zero. If I check `theInstance.result.index` it's still whatever it was before the clear-call. However if I do

```
theInstance.result = new MyResult() { index = 0, depth = 0 }
```

it does work.

Now I don't understand why the clear method doesn't work. Could anyone explain?

Edit: I simplified too much, the result in `MyClass` was a property, and that explains why I'm getting this behavior.

Comment: You should be avoiding mutable structs at all costs.  Clearly at some point in you're code you're creating a copy of the struct and mutating that.  Since you haven't shown a complete example, we cannot possibly say where, specifically.

Comment: Then why did the Unity developers provide a .Clear() method? Or was that a miss on their part as well?

Comment: This is a issue with Unity, I had a clear answer and I was going to post it.

Comment: It is simplified too much, you hid the problem.  Which is surely a property, it returns a copy of the value since a struct is a value type.  You only cleared the copy, not the underlying backing field.

Comment: @TheOddler The issue is with how the mutable struct is used, not how it's defined, but if you don't have a mutable struct to begin with then you have *far* less to be concerned with when using it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah yes! Now I get it, that explains why! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you have shown works ... for bad reasons:

```
    var theInstance = new MyClass();
    theInstance.result.index = 123;
    theInstance.result.depth = 456;
    theInstance.result.Clear();
    System.Console.WriteLine(theInstance.result.index);
    System.Console.WriteLine(theInstance.result.depth);
```

outputs `0` and `0`. However, it will behave differently if the field becomes a property (`{get;set;}`), or if it is placed into a local variable.

Fundamentally, *you should avoid mutable structs*, unless you *really, really* know the what and why. The correct approach here is either:

- make `MyResult` a `class`, or
- make `MyResult` immutable

If you *want* to use a `struct` here, an appropriate implementation might be:

```
public struct MyResult
{
    private readonly float index;
    private readonly int depth;
    public float Index { get { return index; } }
    public int Depth { get { return depth; } }
    public MyResult(float index, int depth)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.depth = depth;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    { /* not shown, but implemented */ }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    { /* not shown, but implemented */ }
    public override string ToString()
    { /* not shown, but implemented */ }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One thing of note, the fields are indeed properties in the real code the OP is looking at in Unity.

Comment: So you reopened the question in order to tell him that he didn't provide a reproducible example, which is exactly what the close reason was?  You should have just left the question closed (at least until the question was fixed to accurately demonstrate the real code).

Comment: Yes, I now realize I simplified my original question too much. I've edited it and now realize why it was happening.

Comment: @Servy I think I've done a bit more than that; while it may not have been reproducible (it is now, note), we can determine *why* the OP was seeing what they were seeing, and provide information and guidance

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah, if that is a unity type it makes things harder; the unity code here is stupid ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell There are any number of ways that the problem could be occurring.  It's most likely that they're copying the `struct`, but even if we can assume that we still can't know *how*.  It could have been a property, or it could have been any number of other differences.